# Optimistic locking in spring boot with related entites

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a question for the following issue: Lets say I have the following Entities:

```
---------------    ----------------
X                  Y
---------------    ----------------
id: long           id: long 
yList: List<Y>     name: String
version: long
```

I want that users of the application can edit all Y's of X's yList as long as no changes on X has been made. When X gets updated (and therefore the version of X increases) I want to prevent that any changes on a 'Y' that belongs to X's previous version number can be stored in the database.

Setting up optimistic locking for X is not the problem, but how do I tell JPA to check the version number of X when saving an Y?